# Unable to find the module which is definitely installed

Tags: python

I've published a module called package-test( i have checked tar.gz file contains all the python files along with egg_info)

Then I installed and extracted this package into my virtual env.
which went fine after looking at the logs of pip and it installed all scripts and dependencies.(supposingly)
 o/p of `pip install -v --user -r requirements.txt --index-url "$(indexURL)"`

looks like

```
Successfully installed  jsonschema-3.2.0 pyyaml-5.3.1 package-test-0.0.0 requests-2.23.0 six-1.14.0 urllib3-1.25.9 zipp-3.1.0
```

requirements.txt --> got the version of tar,gz file

now I can't find anywhere the packages and the python scripts.
I tried to lookinto

```
ls -ltr $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
ls -ltr $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources
```

but no where i can find those scripts.
even I tried search using `pip find package-test` no use also. 
anyone has any idea how can I find all the python scripts in my virtual env after the installation?

has it installed afterall?

edit: 
This is not mac os. The reason I mentioned that it is installed in my virtual env because I enabled `-v` in my pip install and I see that 
copying my packages file . Just showing here one out of many.
`package-test/commonLib/logger.py -> build/lib/package-test/commonLib` 
finally copied to `venv_home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`

The reason I couldn't find it because I was searching in different location.

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/venv_name/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

I think it worked as expected but I was wondering if I can change the location from .local to $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/venv_name/. Is there somewhere I can change it?

Comment: activate your venv, launch your python shell and try to import your package. If this works, you'll find the install path with `yourmoduiename.__file__`. If it doesn't, well, you seem to be using MacOS so I don't even want to try and guess where it could have been installed ;-)

Comment: I activated my venv and all the commands above i was showing is inside my venv. The reason I know, all the files are copied to venv, because I enabled (verbose) in my `pip install` to see where it is copied. I see them it is coping but as soon as start import them, it shows error, as if it's deleted or doesn't exist.  It's not mac :-)

Comment: Sorry, I saw CamelCasedThingies so I though of MacOS (as you can guess I'm not a Window user either xD). Now why didn't you mentionned all those informations in your question ? Please edit your question with all this, AND the exact error message (and full traceback if any) you get, AND your requirements file. Also, import issues don't necessarily mean your package wasn't installed - it may have errors that prevent it from being imported.

Comment: @bruno, there are no error. All I see is successfully installed.And I edit the question. The one thing I found tat packages were copied to `Home_of_venv/.local/lib...` not the `currentDir/venvName/lib/...`  I think it worked as expected that it copied to `$HOME/.local/lib/` but is there a way I can change the location.

Comment: Your question is indeed clearer that way :-) (and sorry, I don't have the answer).